# check permissions of directories in python

Tags: python, chmod

i want a python program that given a directory, it will return all directories within that directory that have 775 (`rwxrwxr-x`) permissions

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither answer recurses, though it's not entirely clear that that's what the OP wants. Here's a recursive approach (untested, but you get the idea):

```
import os
import stat
import sys

MODE = "775"

def mode_matches(mode, file):
    """Return True if 'file' matches 'mode'.

    'mode' should be an integer representing an octal mode (eg
    int("755", 8) -> 493).
    """
    # Extract the permissions bits from the file's (or
    # directory's) stat info.
    filemode = stat.S_IMODE(os.stat(file).st_mode)

    return filemode == mode

try:
    top = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    top = '.'

try:
    mode = int(sys.argv[2], 8)
except IndexError:
    mode = MODE

# Convert mode to octal.
mode = int(mode, 8)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
    dirs = [os.path.join(dirpath, x) for x in dirnames]
    for dirname in dirs:
        if mode_matches(mode, dirname):
            print dirname
```

Something similar is described in the stdlib documentation for
[stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html).

Comment: good solution, you could use int(sys.argv[2], 8) to convert the user octal directly instead of doing it inside the function with the return from stat

Comment: Ah -- indeed! I've updated my answer to convert the desired mode to octal instead of going the other way around for every discovered mode. Thanks!

Comment: you can also just write octal numbers directly if you put a 0 in front of them, e.g. 0777 evaluates to 511 same as int("777", 8)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module.  In particular [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) to look at the permission bits.

```
import  os

for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
   path=os.path.join(dirname, filename)
   if os.path.isdir(path):
       if (os.stat(path).st_mode & 0777) == 0775:
           print path
```

Comment: You could make it more compact and still readable using
"if os.path.isdir(path) and (os.stat(path).st_mode & 0777) == 0775:" instead of two ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Compact generator based on Brian's answer:

```
import os

(fpath for fpath 
   in (os.path.join(dirname,fname) for fname in os.listdir(dirname)) 
   if (os.path.isdir(fpath) and (os.stat(fpath).st_mode & 0777) == 0775))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be python?

You can also use find to do that :

"find . -perm 775"

Answer (score 0):

You can check 775 permission for files and directories using below command

```
path="location of file or directory"
if (oct(os.stat(path).st_mode)[-3:]=="775"):
    print(path)
```