# Check if directory has read/write permissions

Tags: python, directory

My environment is *Python 3.7.2*, running on *Windows 10*.

I am working on some downloader. First of all I want to check if **directory** where I want to download files has *read / write* permissions:

I tried two ways:

1 code:

Using os module (os.access function) to check access, returns True even if I have no write access. Module gives wrong results on Windows:

```
# check for read/write access
if not os.access(path, os.W_OK):
    raise PermissionError("Path %s, doesn't have WRITE permissions" % path)
# check for write access
if not os.access(path, os.R_OK):
     raise PermissionError("Path %s, doesn't have READ permissions" % path)
```

2 code:

The idea to use `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` seemed clean way to check directory permission, with no risk of leaving junk files on the system. The problem is, tempfile.TemporaryFile() hangs on my system when it's given a *dir parameter that hasnt any permissions*,script won't continue to execute or exit. nothing is returned. it's just stuck at that line . The bug affects only Windows environments, but unfortunately it has the result of rendering tempfile.TemporaryFile unusable on Windows for this common use case:

```
import tempfile
import errno

try:
    testfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(dir = path)
    testfile.close()
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES or e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        raise PermissionError("Path %s, doesn't have READ/WRITE permissions" % path)
```

Anyone has idea how to **check permissions of a directory**?

Comment: [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704945/check-permissions-of-directories-in-python), 2nd one will be clear idea, can save downloaded data package in temp folder, program create a error and ask user a new location and , once user provide a valid location assemble the package together  , you can see this package manager [xdm](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm) implementation